# Resultado do serialize estranho

Tags: php

Fiz uma serialização de um objeto em `.php` cujo resultado está muito diferente do comum:

> example.com/script.php?nome=joao&sobrenome=silva&endereco=rua+dos+bobos+numero+zero&cpf=11111111111`)

Este esta sendo o resultado:

> example.com.php?consulta=O:8:"Consulta":4:{s:10:"resultType";s:8:"produtos";s:6:"search";s:12:"lapis%20caneta";s:6:"inicio";N;s:9:"registros";N;}

Código:

```
$string = serialize($consulta);
$url = 'Location:'.'exibir.php?consulta='.$string;
header($url);
```

O que há dentro do objeto:

```
Consulta Object ( [resultType] => produtos [search] => lapis caneta [inicio] => [registros] => )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que você está confundindo a função do PHP com a do jQuery. No PHP, a função [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize)  serve para serializar um objeto de maneira que ele possa ser armazenado, e não utilizado em uma query string de uma requisição HTTP GET.

Para a finalidade que você precisa, use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), que serializa as propriedades públicas de um objeto (também funciona com arrays).

Comment: ,@bfavaretto veja o resultado `exibir.php?resultType=produtos&search=lapis+caneta` a representação esta correta? como posso armazenar isso direto no objeto correspondente?

Comment: Sim, está correta. Você pode desfazer a operação com parse_str ou parse_url dependendo do que passar. Dê uma olhada na documentação dessas funções no manual do PHP.

Comment: Ok, esta forma de passagem de objetos é a forma mais eficiente e correta?

Comment: É a única forma de passar dados via querystring (se entendi o que você está perguntando...)

Comment: Sim o objeto contem valores a serem consultados em um BD

Comment: por que não envia normalmente sem serializar?